# Wordpress saves files as apache user instead of nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos

Uploading content to wordpress would fail, claiming it does not have write permissions for the folder 'uploads'

I set perms to 777 for the uploads folder.

It successfully uploads the file.

Checking with ls -al shows the file is owned by apache with group apache.

This is incorrect and it should be owned by nginx with group nginx.

How do I change this? I do not want to add apache to the nginx group or leave perms open because that's dumb. Wordpress should simply use nginx instead.

Comment: If you run NGINX where is `apache` user coming from? Are you proxying from NGINX to Apache?

Comment: I am not using apache at all, I think wordpress is just hard coded to use apache user.

Comment: That's not a wordpress problem but a server issue. Groups are not set by wordpress. I would ask your hoster for this

Answer (score 0):

The apache user comes from php-fpm. it can be changed by editing the following config file: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

I guess though it seems it is good practice to not use the nginx user for php-fpm, and to create a separate one.

So the solution in the end is to either make a new user for php-fpm and assign it in that config, then add it to the necessary group for the uploads folder, and any other folder you wish to have write access to with php.